# Why do you have to provide the parser twice when creating an OptionGroup?

Tags: python, optparse

According to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#grouping-options), you have to provide the parser when creating the OptionGroup:

```
group = OptionGroup(parser, "Dangerous Options",
                    "Caution: use these options at your own risk.  "
                    "It is believed that some of them bite.")
```

And then explicitly add it after you're done creating the `OptionGroup`:

```
parser.add_option_group(group)
```

I do not have access the source code at the moment but will later on. Perhaps someone else knows.

Answer (score 1):

`OptionGroup` derives from `OptionContainer` (so does `OptionParser`), which provides (among other methods) `add_option` and `_check_conflict`. The `parser` argument is used to provide some arguments to its parent `__init__` method:

```
class OptionGroup (OptionContainer):

    def __init__(self, parser, title, description=None):
        self.parser = parser 
        OptionContainer.__init__(
            self, parser.option_class, parser.conflict_handler, description)
        self.title = title
```

`self.parser` is used in one other place for a similar purpose. So I think you pass `parser` to `__init__` just so that the option group will behave the same way as the parser when you add options to it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the OptParse developer didn't add

```
parser.add_option_group(self)
```

in the OptionGroup class constructor.

:P